# I can't use char names in if statements

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    char sexo;
    float alt,peso;
    printf("Qual o seu sexo? (M/F)");
    sexo=getch();
    printf("Insira a sua altura: ");
    scanf("&f", &alt);
    if (sexo=m||sexo=M||sexo=f||sexo=F)
    {
        if (sexo=m||sexo=M)
        peso=(72.7*alt)-58;
        else
        peso=(62.1*alt)-44.7;
        printf("O peso recomendado para o seu sexo e %.2fKg",peso);
    }
    else
        printf("Sexo invalido");
}
```

Once I try to compile this I get errors on line 11 saying:

```
error: 'm' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: 'M' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: 'f' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: 'F' undeclared (first use in this function)

||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===||
```

Anyone knows what's happening?

Comment: chars take single quotes like `'M'`. Use `sexo == 'm' || sexo == 'M'`

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they way you used m & M & f & F is like they are variable not characters 
this is what you meant to do

2- the comparison operator is ==  not = only ( which is the assignment operator)

```
if (sexo=='m'||sexo=='M'||sexo=='f'||sexo=='F')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
if (sexo=m||sexo=M||sexo=f||sexo=F)
```

by

```
if (sexo=='m'||sexo=='M'||sexo=='f'||sexo=='F')
```

Character constants are enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, You must use `==` if you want to compare two value,  not `=`. A single equel (`=`) is used for initial a value in a variable.

**Secondly**, If you want to compare a value with a character you must put a single quotation before and after it, like `sexo == 'A'`. Comparing it without quotation, like `sexo == A` means that you compare it with *value of variable A* not the *value of A*. So you need to change your code in following way:

Change:

```
if (sexo=m||sexo=M||sexo=f||sexo=F)
```

To:

```
if (sexo=='m'||sexo=='M'||sexo=='f'||sexo=='F')
```

And change:

```
if (sexo=m||sexo=M)
```

To:

```
if (sexo=='m'||sexo=='M')
```